# Reload component Y imported with 'from X import Y'

Tags: python, python-import

In Python, once I have imported a module X in an interpreter session using `import X`, and the module changes on the outside, I can reload the module with `reload(X)`. The changes then become available in my interpreter session.

I am wondering if this also possible when I import a component Y from module X using `from X import Y`.

The statement `reload Y` does not work, since `Y` is not a module itself, but only a component (in this case a class) inside of a module.

Is it possible at all to reload individual components of a module without leaving the interpreter session (or importing the entire module)?

For clarification, the question is about importing a **class or function Y** from a **module X** and reloading on a change, not a module Y from a package X.

Comment: I believe there is a contradiction in this question: "`... possible ... import a component Y from module X`" vs "`question is ... importing a class or function X from a module Y`". I'm adding an edit to that effect.

Comment: it appears that the marked answer does not actually answer the question, I believe mine does. Can you update/comment?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If Y is a module (and X a package) `reload(Y)` will be fine -- otherwise, you'll see why good Python style guides (such as my employer's) say to **never** import anything **except** a module (this is one out of many great reasons -- yet people still keep importing functions and classes directly, no matter how much I explain that it's **not** a good idea;-).

Comment: I see your point. Would you care to elaborate on any of the other good reasons why it is not a good idea?

Comment: @cschol: Zen of Python, last verse (`import this` from interactive prompt to see the Zen of Python); and all the reasons _why_ namespaces are a honking great idea (immediate local visual clues that the name's being looked up, ease of mocking/injecting in tests, ability to reload, ability for a module to change flexibly by redefining some entries, predictable and controllable behavior on serialization and recovery of your data [[e.g. by pickling and unpickling]], and so on, and so forth -- a SO comment is hardly long enough to do justice to this rich, long argument!!!-)

Comment: +1 for answer, rich, long comment and mentioning your employer's style guide. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if it might be because of the contradiction confusion in the OP, but this appears to be incorrect.

Comment: note that in Python 3, reload is no longer in the default namespace but has been moved to the `importlib` package.  `importlib.reload(Y)` https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/importlib.html?highlight=reload#functions see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961162/reloading-module-giving-error-reload-is-not-defined

Comment: @AlexMartelli Does this guideline basically mean "never use `from`"?

Comment: @ThorSummoner, absolutely not -- it means "always import MODULES", so "from my.package import mymodule" is absolutely fine and indeed preferred -- just, never import classes, functions, etc -- always, only, ever *modules*.

Comment: Downvote. Why? This is not the right answer. The right answer was given by Catskul on Jul 30 '12 at 15:04.

Comment: the problem is I learnt from answers like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21995949/2262424 and seems like I was not the only one... shall I rather proceed with https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597/2262424 ?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187403/import-module-vs-from-module-import-function/187432#187432?newreg=e144eff5613f41c7984c203d22271de7

Answer (score 144):

#### Answer

From my tests, the marked answer, which suggests a simple `reload(X)`, does not work.

From what I can tell the correct answer is:

```
from importlib import reload # python 2.7 does not require this
import X
reload( X )
from X import Y
```

---

#### Test

My test was the following (Python 2.6.5 + bpython 0.9.5.2)

X.py:

```
def Y():
    print "Test 1"
```

bpython:

```
>>> from X import Y
>>> print Y()
Test 1
>>> # Edit X.py to say "Test 2"
>>> print Y()
Test 1
>>> reload( X )  # doesn't work because X not imported yet
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'X' is not defined
>>> import X
>>> print Y()
Test 1
>>> print X.Y()
Test 1
>>> reload( X ) # No effect on previous "from" statements
>>> print Y()
Test 1
>>> print X.Y() # first one that indicates refresh
Test 2
>>> from X import Y
>>> print Y()
Test 2 
>>> # Finally get what we were after
```

Comment: Wow. I found this really handy. Thanks! I use this as one liner now: import X; reload( X ); from X import Y

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted one. It's fair to warn people, but everyone's use case is different. In some cases it really is helpful to reload a class, eg when you're using the python console and want to load changes to your code without losing your session.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work always. I have a module `Foo` which has an `__init__.py` that fetches a submodule... I'll post an answer as a counterexample.

Comment: Python 3 one liner now: import importlib;import X; importlib.reload( X ); from X import Y

Comment: well in this answer you must now import x right?

Comment: it is ugly but it is the only thing that I know of that gets the job done...thanks.

Answer (score 29):

```
from modulename import func

import importlib, sys
importlib.reload(sys.modules['modulename'])
from modulename import func
```

Comment: This is the best way imo because you might not remember exactly how it was imported

Comment: That's the only working solution to the original question, and has too few votes!

Comment: In python2 do the same but without importing of the importlib - just call reload(), which is a standalone command in python2.

Answer (score 6):

First off, you shouldn't be using reload at all, if you can avoid it. But let's assume you have your reasons (i.e. debugging inside IDLE).

Reloading the library won't get the names back into the module's namespace. To do this, just reassign the variables:

```
f = open('zoo.py', 'w')
f.write("snakes = ['viper','anaconda']\n")
f.close()

from zoo import snakes
print snakes

f = open('zoo.py', 'w')
f.write("snakes = ['black-adder','boa constrictor']\n")
f.close()

import zoo
reload(zoo)
snakes = zoo.snakes # the variable 'snakes' is now reloaded

print snakes
```

You could do this a few other ways. You could automate the process by searching through the local namespace, and reassigning anything that was from the module in question, but I think we are being evil enough.

Answer (score 5):

If you're working in a jupyter environment, and you already have `from module import function` can use the magic function, `autoreload` by

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload
from module import function
```

The introduction of the `autoreload` in IPython is given [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do this:

```
from mymodule import myobject
```

Do this instead:

```
import mymodule
myobject=mymodule.myobject
```

You can now use myobject in the same way as you were planning (without the tiresome unreadable mymodule references everywhere).

If you're working interactively and want to reload myobject from mymodule you now can using:

```
reload(mymodule)
myobject=mymodule.myobject
```

Answer (score 3):

assuming you used `from X import Y`, you have two options:

```
reload(sys.modules['X'])
reload(sys.modules[__name__]) # or explicitly name your module
```

or

```
Y=reload(sys.modules['X']).Y
```

few considerations:

A. if the import scope is not module-wide (e,g: import in a function) - you must use the second version.

B. if Y is imported into X from another module (Z) - you must reload Z, than reload X and than reload your module, even reloading all your modules (e,g: using `[ reload(mod) for mod in sys.modules.values() if type(mod) == type(sys) ]`) might reload X before reloading Z - and than not refresh the value of Y.

Answer (score 1):

1. `reload()` module `X`,
2. `reload()` module importing `Y` from `X`.

Note that reloading won't change already created objects bound in other namespaces (even if you follow style guide from Alex).

Answer (score 1):

Just to follow up on [AlexMartelli's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1739931/44330) and [Catskul's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11724154/44330) answers, there are some really simple but nasty cases that appear to confound `reload`, at least in Python 2.

Suppose I have the following source tree:

```
- foo
  - __init__.py
  - bar.py
```

with the following content:

init.py:

```
from bar import Bar, Quux
```

bar.py:

```
print "Loading bar"

class Bar(object):
  @property
  def x(self):
     return 42

class Quux(Bar):
  object_count = 0
  def __init__(self):
     self.count = self.object_count
     self.__class__.object_count += 1
  @property
  def x(self):
     return super(Quux,self).x + 1
  def __repr__(self):
     return 'Quux[%d, x=%d]' % (self.count, self.x)
```

This works just fine without using `reload`:

```
>>> from foo import Quux
Loading bar
>>> Quux()
Quux[0, x=43]
>>> Quux()
Quux[1, x=43]
>>> Quux()
Quux[2, x=43]
```

But try to reload and it either has no effect or corrupts things:

```
>>> import foo
Loading bar
>>> from foo import Quux
>>> Quux()
Quux[0, x=43]
>>> Quux()
Quux[1, x=43]
>>> reload(foo)
<module 'foo' from 'foo\__init__.pyc'>
>>> Quux()
Quux[2, x=43]
>>> from foo import Quux
>>> Quux()
Quux[3, x=43]
>>> reload(foo.bar)
Loading bar
<module 'foo.bar' from 'foo\bar.pyc'>
>>> Quux()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "foo\bar.py", line 17, in __repr__
    return 'Quux[%d, x=%d]' % (self.count, self.x)
  File "foo\bar.py", line 15, in x
    return super(Quux,self).x + 1
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
>>> Quux().count
5
>>> Quux().count
6
>>> Quux = foo.bar.Quux
>>> Quux()
Quux[0, x=43]
>>> foo.Quux()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "foo\bar.py", line 17, in __repr__
    return 'Quux[%d, x=%d]' % (self.count, self.x)
  File "foo\bar.py", line 15, in x
    return super(Quux,self).x + 1
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
>>> foo.Quux().count
8
```

The only way I could ensure the `bar` submodule was reloaded was to `reload(foo.bar)`; the only way I access the reloaded `Quux` class is to reach in and grab it from the reloaded sub module; but the `foo` module itself kept holding onto the original `Quux` class object, presumably because it uses `from bar import Bar, Quux` (rather than `import bar` followed by `Quux = bar.Quux`); furthermore the `Quux` class got out of sync with itself, which is just bizarre.