# In Python, is the idiom "from Module import ClassName" typical?

Tags: import, python

Since I prefer small files, I typically place a single "public" class per Python module. I name the module with the same name as the class it contains. So for example, the class `ToolSet` would be defined in `ToolSet.py`.

Within a package, if another module needs to instanciate an object of class ToolSet, I use:

```
from ToolSet import ToolSet
...
toolSet = ToolSet()
```

instead of:

```
import ToolSet
...
toolSet = ToolSet.ToolSet()
```

I do this to reduce "stutter" (I prefer to have stutter at the top of the file than within my code.)

Is this a correct idiom?

Here is a related question. Within a package, I often have a small number of classes that I would like to expose to the outside world. These I import inside the `__init__.py` for that package. For example, if `ToolSet` is in package `UI` and I want to expose it, I would put the following in `UI/__init__.py` :

```
from ToolSet import ToolSet
```

So that, from an external module I can write

```
import UI
...
toolSet = UI.ToolSet()
```

Again, is this pythonic?

Comment: @Philippe: you may be interested in reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744258/is-import-module-better-coding-style-than-from-module-import-function

Comment: Thanks unutbu. My searches didn't return this questions.

Comment: To prevent confusion between the two ToolSet items (both the module name and the class name), you'd better follow the pep8 guideline that suggests to use a lowercase-only module name (so "from toolset import ToolSet" or "toolset.ToolSet".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your first question, that is the idiom I use, and its use is supported by [PEP8 the python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

> it's okay to say this though:
>
> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

I like it as it reduces typing and makes sure that things go wrong immediately the file is run (say you mis-spelt an import) rather than some time later when a function using the import is run.

Eg suppose the module `Thing` doesn't have a `Thyng` member

```
from Thing import Thyng
```

Goes wrong immediately you run the `.py` file, whereas

```
import Thing
# ...
def fn():
    Thing.Thyng()
```

Doesn't go wrong until you run `fn()`

As for your second question, I think that is also good practice.  It often happens to me when I factor a single large.py into a directory with an `__init__.py` and implementation files.  Importing things into the `__init__.py` keeps the interface the same.  It is common practice in the standard libraries too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Both are idiomatic Python in my opinion.

I tend to use the `from module import name` form for some modules in the standard library, such as `datetime`, but mostly for closely related modules, or names that are frequently used in the module. For example, I typically import ORM classes in this way.

I tend to use the `import module` form for some standard modules (especially `os` and `os.path`) and for names that are not very distinctive (like `database.session` and `cherrypy.session` being two different kind of sessions) and for name that are used infrequently where the mention of the module name improves readability.

In the end, there are a few rules of thumb (such as `import os.path`), but which form to use is largely a matter of judgement, taste and experience.

Answer (score 0):

To address if it is pythonic, take a look at what is generally the definitive answer on the internet: http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

Also take a look at ~unutbu's link which discusses this in greater detail.

Answer (score 0):

I use `from itertools import chain, ifilter, islice, izip` all the time, because it allows me to program as though those were built-in methods, which to my way of thinking they really ought to be.

Once, in a frenzy of misguided correctness, I went through a big block of code and replaced `from datetime import datetime` with `import datetime`.  This was a good example of Mark Twain's observation that a man who picks up a rat by the tail learns something that can be learned no other way.  It certainly set me straight on why it's OK to use `from x import y`.