# name 'OptionGroup' is not defined

Tags: python, optparse, nameerror

This error is done strictly by following [examples found on the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#generating-help). And you can't find any clarification about it anywhere, be it [that long long docs page](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#tutorial), [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=python+%22name+'OptionGroup'+is+not+defined%22) or [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=optiongroup+%5Bpython%5D). Plus, reading `optparse.py` shows OptionGroup is there, so that adds to the confusion.

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Feb 11 2010, 00:51:29) 
>>> from optparse import OptionParser
>>> outputGroup = OptionGroup(parser, 'Output handling')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'OptionGroup' is not defined
```

I bet it will take less than 1 minute for someone to spot my error. :)

Yes, that means I knew the answer, but since this took me so long to discover I wanted to "document" it here.

Comment: @SLott sure... but my point is that I just asked the question I already know the answer to, only to "catalog" somewhere. Because I took quite a long time to figure it out, and could find no reference to this issue. feel free to edit it yourself, but what you suggest I could do? I don't mind deleting this, I just figured it could help someone else who may fall the same trap I did. - btw the question is quite explicit under the *quoted coded error*.

Comment: @SLott How about now? I didn't really wanted to take of the personal storytelling that was giving the background, but I always agree when there's a way to make shorter the ever-boring-wording-reading, which is about anything we can read! - plus the little background is now documented anyway on the comments and revisions, thanks to you. ;P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps this is [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828953/silent-the-stdout-of-a-function-in-python-without-trashing-sys-stdout-and-restori/2829036#2829036) of why it is [better to import modules than functions from modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744258/is-import-module-better-coding-style-than-from-module-import-function).

`OptionGroup` is defined in the module `optparse`.
The command

`from optparse import OptionParser`

puts `OptionParser` in the global namespace, but neglects `OptionGroup` entirely.

To fix the code, import the `optparse` module, and access its parts like so:

```
import optparse
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
outputGroup = optparse.OptionGroup(parser, 'Output handling')
```

Comment: precisely the problem. and I agree with the "better way to import modules" but I actually *fixed it* going along with the docs and using  `from optparse import OptionParser, OptionGroup` - btw, took you long enough! ;D