# How to handle tokenization errors?

Tags: python, tokenize, stringio

Please find below the piece of code that I use to tokenize a string.

```
strList = list(token[STRING] for token in generate_tokens(StringIO(line).readline) if token[STRING])
```

I get an error that reads like:-

```
    raise TokenError, ("EOF in multi-line statement", (lnum, 0))
tokenize.TokenError: ('EOF in multi-line statement', (2, 0))
```

I wish to ignore such errors and be able to complete the tokenization process. I have a lot of data, so I am okay with loosing a part of the data to these errors. However, I am not sure how to write the piece of code that would enable be to implement the desired functionality. Could some one help me out with the code please?

Thank you.

Edit1:-

on trying the

```
except tokenize.TokenError:
    pass
```

I get the following error message

```
    except tokenize.TokenError:
 NameError: name 'tokenize' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that your error message says `tokenize.TokenError`. That is the type of `Exception` your code is raising. To catch the error, you use a `try...except` block. To skip the error you simply put `pass` in the `except` block.

```
import tokenize
try:
    strList = list(token[STRING] for token in tokenize.generate_tokens(StringIO(line).readline) if token[STRING])
except tokenize.TokenError:
    pass
```

Comment: Sorry it worked. I hadn't imported the tokenize module. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah right. I missed that you were using `generate_tokens` rather than `tokenize.generate_tokens`. I try to avoid barenames because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744258/is-import-module-better-coding-style-than-from-module-import-function