# How to glob for iterable element

Tags: python

I have a python dictionary that contains iterables, some of which are lists, but most of which are other dictionaries. I'd like to do glob-style assignment similar to the following:

```
myiter['*']['*.txt']['name'] = 'Woot'
```

That is, for each element in myiter, look up all elements with keys ending in '.txt' and then set their 'name' item to 'Woot'.

I've thought about sub-classing dict and using the fnmatch module.  But, it's unclear to me what the *best* way of accomplishing this is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way, I think, would be **not** to do it -- `'*'` is a perfectly valid key in a dict, so `myiter['*']` has a perfectly well defined meaning and usefulness, and subverting that can definitely cause problems.  How to "glob" over keys which are **not** strings, including the exclusively integer "keys" (indices) in elements which are lists and not mappings, is also quite a design problem.

If you nevertheless **must** do it, I would recommend taking full control by subclassing the [abstract base class](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#abcs-abstract-base-classes) `collections.MutableMapping`, and *implement* the needed methods (`__len__`, `__iter__`, `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`, and, for better performance, also override others such as `__contains__`, which the ABC does implement on the base of the others, but slowly) in terms of a contained `dict`.  Subclassing `dict` instead, as per other suggestions, would require you to override a huge number of methods to avoid inconsistent behavior between the use of "keys containing wildcards" in the methods you do override, and in those you don't.

Whether you subclass `collections.MutableMapping`, or `dict`, to make your `Globbable` class, you have to make a core design decision: what does `yourthing[somekey]` *return* when `yourthing` is a `Globbable`?

Presumably it has to return a different type when `somekey` is a string containing wildcards, versus anything else.  In the latter case, one would imagine, just what is actually at that entry; but in the former, it can't just return another `Globbable` -- otherwise, what would `yourthing[somekey] = 'bah'` **do** in the general case?  For your single "slick syntax" example, you want it to set a `somekey` entry in each of the *items* of `yourthing` (a **HUGE** semantic break with the behavior of every other mapping in the universe;-) -- but then, how would you ever set an entry in `yourthing` itself?!

Let's see if the Zen of Python has anything to say about this "slick syntax" for which you yearn...:

```
>>> import this
    ...
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
```

Consider for a moment the alternative of losing the "slick syntax" (and all the **huge** semantic headaches it necessarily implies) in favor of clarity and simplicity (using Python 2.7-and-better syntax here, just for the dict comprehension -- use an explicit `dict(...)` call instead if you're stuck with 2.6 or earlier), e.g.:

```
def match(s, pat):
    try: return fnmatch.fnmatch(s, pat)
    except TypeError: return False

def sel(ds, pat):
    return [d[k] for d in ds for k in d if match(k, pat)]

def set(ds, k, v):
    for d in ds: d[k] = v
```

so your assignment might become

```
set(sel(sel([myiter], '*')), '*.txt'), 'name', 'Woot')
```

(the selection with `'*'` being redundant if all , I'm just omitting it).  Is this **so** horrible as to be worth the morass of issues I've mentioned above in order to use instead

```
myiter['*']['*.txt']['name'] = 'Woot'
```

...?  By far the clearest and best-performing way, of course, remains the even-simpler

```
def match(k, v, pat):
    try:
      if fnmatch.fnmatch(k, pat):
        return isinstance(v, dict)
    except TypeError:
        return False

for k, v in myiter.items():
  if match(k, v, '*'):
    for sk, sv in v.items():
      if match(sk, sv, '*.txt'):
        sv['name'] = 'Woot'
```

but if you absolutely crave conciseness and compactness, despising the Zen of Python's koan "Sparse is better than dense", you *can* at least obtain them without the various nightmares I mentioned as needed to achieve your ideal "syntax sugar".

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to subclass dict and use the fnmatch module.

- subclass dict: adding functionality you want in an object-oriented way.
- fnmatch module: reuse of existing functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`fnmatch`](http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html) for functionality to match on dictionary keys although you would have to compromise syntax slightly, especially if you wanted to do this on a nested dictionary.  Perhaps a custom dictionary-like class with a search method to return wildcard matches would work well.

Here is a VERY BASIC example that comes with a warning that this is NOT RECURSIVE and will not handle nested dictionaries:

```
from fnmatch import fnmatch

class GlobDict(dict):
    def glob(self, match):
        """@match should be a glob style pattern match (e.g. '*.txt')"""
        return dict([(k,v) for k,v  in self.items() if fnmatch(k, match)])

# Start with a basic dict
basic_dict = {'file1.jpg':'image', 'file2.txt':'text', 'file3.mpg':'movie',
              'file4.txt':'text'}

# Create a GlobDict from it
glob_dict = GlobDict( **basic_dict )

# Then get glob-styl results!
globbed_results = glob_dict.glob('*.txt')
# => {'file4.txt': 'text', 'file2.txt': 'text'}
```

As for what way is the *best*? The best way is the one that works. Don't try to optimize a solution before it's even created!

Answer (score 1):

Following the principle of least magic, perhaps just define a recursive function, rather than subclassing `dict`:

```
import fnmatch

def set_dict_with_pat(it,key_patterns,value):
    if len(key_patterns)>1:
        for key in it:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(key,key_patterns[0]):
                set_dict_with_pat(it[key],key_patterns[1:],value)
    else:
        for key in it:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(key,key_patterns[0]):
                it[key]=value
```

Which could be used like this:

```
myiter=({'dir1':{'a.txt':{'name':'Roger'},'b.notxt':{'name':'Carl'}},'dir2':{'b.txt':{'name':'Sally'}}})
set_dict_with_pat(myiter,['*','*.txt','name'],'Woot')
print(myiter)
# {'dir2': {'b.txt': {'name': 'Woot'}}, 'dir1': {'b.notxt': {'name': 'Carl'}, 'a.txt': {'name': 'Woot'}}}
```

Comment: replacing import fnmatch with from fnmatch import fnmatch would get rid of those inconvenient fnmatch.fnmatches.

Comment: @Tony: Thanks for the suggestion. However, this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744258/is-import-module-better-coding-style-than-from-module-import-function/1744439#1744439) has convinced me that `import module` is a better coding style than `from module import function`.