# How to limit FPGrowth itemesets to just 2 or 3

Tags: pyspark, python-3.6

I am running the FPGrowth algorithm using pyspark in python3.6 using jupyter notebook. When I am trying to save the association rules output of rules generated is huge. So I want to limit the number of consequent. Here is the code which I have tried. I also changed the spark context parameters.

[Maximum Pattern Length fpGrowth (Apache) PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51552296/maximum-pattern-length-fpgrowth-apache-pyspark)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, size
from pyspark.ml.fpm import FPGrowth
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("App")
conf = (conf.setMaster('local[*]')
        .set('spark.executor.memory', '100G')
        .set('spark.driver.memory', '400G')
        .set('spark.driver.maxResultSize', '200G'))
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)
R = Row('ID', 'items')
df=spark.createDataFrame([R(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(lol)])
fpGrowth = FPGrowth(itemsCol="items", minSupport=0.7, minConfidence=0.9)

model = fpGrowth.fit(df)
ar=model.associationRules.where(size(col('antecedent')) == 2).where(size(col('cosequent')) == 1)

ar.cache()
ar.toPandas().to_csv('output.csv')
```

```
     It gives an error


   TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-1-f90c7a9f11ae> in <module>

   ---> 73 ar=model.associationRules.where(size(col('antecedent')) == 
  2).where(size(col('consequent')) == 1)
   TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Can someone help me to solve the issue.

Here lol is list of list of transactions: [['a','b'],['c','a','e']....]

Python: 3.6.5
Pyspark
Windows 10

Comment: Can you please show us the complete error message? The following works fine: `ar=model.associationRules.where(F.size(F.col('antecedent')) == 2).where(F.size(F.col('consequent')) == 1)` `ar.show()`. Please keep in mind that the column is called consequent and not cosequent.

Comment: what is F here? I have updated the error

Comment: It comes from `from pyspark.sql import functions as F`. The error message you get is not an spark issue, it is a python issue. Have you defined a variable with the name `size` or `col` somewhere? Try to restart your jupyter kernel.

Comment: Done. Thanks. I defined it as F and then used F.col and F.size. But I have one more question which I will post shortly. Please look into that.

Answer (score 0):

From the above discussion and following this link, it helped me to resolve the problem.

['str' object is not callable TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775541/str-object-is-not-callable-typeerror)

```
   import pyspark.sql.functions as func
   model.associationRules.where(func.size(func.col('antecedent')) == 1).where(func.size(func.col('consequent')) == 1).show()
```

Comment: Could you please add the actual solution to your answer? This will make your answer more valuable and helps others to find an answer more quickly.