# How can I invoke a function from an imported module inside a class methode?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, subprocess, class-method

I am trying to make a small GUI program with tkinter. I need to use Python's

```
subprocess.call()
```

When I try to do so inside a class method I get following error:

```
    self.return_code = self.subprocess.call("echo Hello World", shell=True)
AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'subprocess'
```

Here is part of my program:

```
from tkinter import *
from subprocess import call

class App:
    def __init__(self, mainframe):
        self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="10 10 12 12", relief=GROOVE) 
        self.mainframe.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

        self.proceedButton = ttk.Button(self.mainframe, text="Proceed", command=self.proceed)
        self.proceedButton.grid(column=0, row=9, sticky=(W))

    def proceed(self):
        self.proceedButton.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.return_code = self.subprocess.call("echo Hello World", shell=True)
```

The last line inside the proceed function throws the error.

I am learning Python. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `subprocess.call` instead of `self.subprocess.call`:

```
import subprocess
self.return_code = subprocess.call("echo Hello World", shell=True)
```

`self` is an instance of `App`. `subprocess` is a module. To understand why `self.subprocess` is wrong, read the "[Random Remarks](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks)" from the Python tutorial on Classes. Then read about modules, and [how to call a module's functions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#modules).

Comment: This trows another error:

    self.return_code = subprocess.call("echo Hello World", shell=True)
NameError: global name 'subprocess' is not defined

This Works:
self.return_code = call("echo Hello World", shell=True)

Comment: Indeed, if you use `from subprocess import call`, then you can write `call(...)` instead of `subprocess.call(...)`. I tend to [always import modules](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1744258/190597), however.