# How does Python handle imported subclasses?

Tags: python, class, import, subclass

I am working on a project that requires me to build several classes and subclasses in one file, and use them in a second file. I would like to ask how Python handles importing the first file into the second.

For instance, if i have a file my_classes.py:

```
class Myclass(object):
    pass

class Mysubclass(myclass):
    pass
```

will using the following code work:

```
from my_classes import Myclass

print Mysubclass
```

(where the `print` command is just an example of using `Mysubclass`), or do I need to import `Mysubclass` explicitly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not try this code and see if there is an error?

Comment: Seems like the obvious solution and indeed answers my question. However, I would like some background information on why Python behaves the way it does (e.g. why are subclasses not automatically loaded when the class is imported).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work. Python `import` statement doesn't care about subclasses. Actually, it doesn't care about anything. It does precisely what you tell it to do. "Explicit is better than implicit" is a popular saying in Python circles.

Here:

```
from my_classes import Myclass
```

You told Python to import only `Myclass`.

This will import both classes:

```
from my_classes import Myclass, Mysubclass
```

You can read how Python `import` works [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-import_stmt).

Comment: Thanks! The link you provided goes a little beyond my comprehension, but answers the question I had.

Answer (score 0):

Your subclass will not be available if you do it like this. You must import every object by itself.

Here a quick example

test_class.py
    class MyClass(object):
        def **init**(self):
            print self.**class**

```
class MySubClass(MyClass):
    def __init__(self):
        print self.__class__
```

test_class_import.py
    from test_class import MyClass

```
MyClass()
MySubClass()

##output##
<class 'test_class.MyClass'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_class2.py", line 4, in <module>
    MySubClass()
NameError: name 'MySubClass' is not defined
```

but

```
from test_class import MyClass, MySubClass
MyClass()
MySubClass()

##output##
<class 'test_class.MyClass'>
<class 'test_class.MySubClass'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every module has a namespace.

A namespace is a mapping from variable names to values (Python objects).

The statement

```
import my_classes
```

makes the `my_classes` namespace accessible from the current module by placing the variable name `my_classes` in the current module's namespace. You can then access values from `my_classes` with the syntax

```
my_classes.variable
```

So, for example:

```
import my_classes
print my_classes.Mysubclass
print my_classes.MyClass
```

If that is too much typing, I suggest

```
import my_classes as MC
print MC.Mysubclass
print MC.MyClass
```

you could also do

```
from my_classes import Mysubclass, MyClass
```

but this form of import is [discouraged by some Python experts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1744258/190597).

```
from my_classes import Mysubclass, MyClass
```

loads the entire module `my_class` but only
places the variable names `Mysubclass` and `MyClass` in the current module's namespace. They point to the same values as do the variables of the same name in the `my_classes` namespace. You don't get access to anything else from the `my_class` module's namespace.