# Unable to use datetime.strptime with from datetime import datetime

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having some confusion on some of my code which was previously working (yesterday). Using python 2.7.6

I had

```
from datetime import datetime

openfor = (datetime.strptime(row[1],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") - datetime.strptime(row[2], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")).total_seconds()
```

and it returned the value that is required. As of this morning it is generating

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'
```

If I use the below, with or without the import it works.

```
openfor = (datetime.datetime.strptime(row[1],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") - datetime.datetime.strptime(row[2], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")).total_seconds()
```

It is no real big deal, because it works, but the code looks ugly and my curiosity is piqued.
So any suggestions on why this would stop working? And how to resolve?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the comments, the import statement

```
from pylab import *
```

is the cause of the problem. This imports `pylab` *and* copies all the names in the `pylab` namespace into the global namespace of the current module. `datetime` is one of those names:

```
In [188]: import pylab

In [189]: 'datetime' in dir(pylab)
Out[189]: True
```

So `datetime` is getting reassigned to the module rather than the class.

---

Somewhere between

```
from datetime import datetime
```

and

```
openfor = (datetime.strptime(row[1],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") - datetime.strptime(row[2], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")).total_seconds()
```

`datetime` is getting redefined to equal the module `datetime` rather than the class `datetime.datetime`. 
The cause of this problem is in code that you have not posted.
(But an import statement,  `import datetime`, is likely the culprit. Also be careful not to use `from module import *`, as this could pollute the calling module's namespace with names from the other module. This could include `datetime`.)

---

By the way, [some experts recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744258/is-import-module-better-coding-style-than-from-module-import-function) never using

```
from module import function
```

and instead always importing modules only:

```
import module         # or 
import module as foo
```

While this may be a stylistic choice, adhering to this rule makes it extremely clear where everything is coming from.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply, the other imports are as follows `import sqlite3
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from datetime import datetime
from time import strftime
from pylab import *`

Comment: The issue is the last one; `from pylab import *` includes `datetime` (the module).

Comment: I would up vote your answer, but don't yet have enough reputation. Thanks for the style tips too.