# are there performance advantages to "import ... from ..."?

Tags: python, python-import

I will be writing (amateur) code which is more CPU and memory intensive than the one I used before. I noticed in other's code that some favor

```
import something
(...)
a = something.method()
```

over

```
from something import method
(...)
a = method()
```

Are there performance advantages to use one style versus the other?

[PEP-0008 discusses imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008#imports) but after reading this, it looks to my untrained eye that the two cases described above are more a matter of taste / style. I prefer to type `a = something.method()` because I will understand my code better. This said, if this really impacts performance I will switch.

Note: the question is not about personal preferences but actual performance hit (or lack of) for the two import styles.That aspect was nicely discussed [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744258/is-import-module-better-coding-style-than-from-module-import-function).

Comment: The first way is the preferred way, because it is more explicit. The second way is for if you're too lazy to type `something.` throughout your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference in performance is that one includes an extra attribute lookup:

```
a = something.method()
```

while the other references `method` *directly*:

```
a = method()
```

which is countered by the `from ... import ...` statement performing the lookup when binding the name. This difference between these actions is *negligible*.

Importing is really just binding names to *already loaded objects*. Python loads the whole module the first time if it wasn't yet available, but how you then bind names has no influence over what is loaded.

As such, this is a style choice. People like to be able to determine, at a glance, where an object came from. Importing the module rather than objects from the module gives you this visual reference.

Comment: Using `timeit`, I get ~0.7us for `import os`, ~2us for both `from os import path` and `from os import open`; Using `import os; os.open` gives me ~0.8us, and `from os import open; open` gives me ~2us... I'm not sure *why* this is, and the difference certainly is negligible in CPU performance; but perhaps there is a memory advantage if you're using large modules and import less (ie. importing all of `PyQT` is usually not required for most applications)?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I think in the one case there is a lookup in the global namespace and then descending into `os`, in the other case you descend directly into `os` explicitly.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: how did you run those `timeit` tests? Take into account that `timeit` names are created as *locals*, so looking up the names again has a different performance effect than using globals. `from ... import ...` does more work than `import` as it has to look up the name to bind to (in addition to finding the module object first), so you'd expect it to take a fraction longer. Apparently that lookup is a little slower than the attribute lookup from `os.open` though.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: there is no memory advantage here; all of the module is loaded and stored in `sys.modules`; the `import` statement merely adds references to your current namespace doing the importing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters http://pastebin.com/RUi1Myfr ... Results seem consistent, regardless of the order I run them in... The bytecode also explains why it takes (slightly) longer

Comment: I also seem to get a consist *higher* memory usage with `from os import open` (as reported by `resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF)`), probably since Python now has an extra reference to keep track of... I've always assumed that this would take less memory...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: I'll look into this a little when I have more time. The same tests with Python 2 show a smaller difference, but the Python 3 import machinery has seen a big overhaul in Python 3 and a lot of it is handled in Python code there, which could explain the extra time taken.

Comment: Hmm, in Python 2.7.8 I get similar results on my Arch Linux machine than I get with Python 3, but on my FreeBSD machine using `from os import open` in Python 2 seems to be faster than `import os`...? Using Python3 on FreeBSD gives similar results to Arch.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: looking at the 2.7 source and the disassembly the only difference between `from mod import name; name` and `import mod; mod.name` is stack actions; `IMPORT_FROM` pushes the name onto the stack (`PUSH`, then later does an extra `POP_TOP` to remove the module object again after the name is set). `LOAD_ATTR` (for the `mod.name` case) *replaces* the top item on the stack (`SET_TOP`). That is it, really.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: Python 3 hasn't changed in that regard; the only difference here is that `from ... import ...` pushes an extra item onto the stack. That's an extra microsecond, apparently.