# Reload module in python

Tags: python, module, reload

When I import a class `MyClass` from a file `myModule.py` from with a `myModules` dictionary i do it like

```
from myModules.myModule import MyClass
```

How to reload this module after I have made changes to the file `myModue.py`? Here are some mistrials:

```
reload(MyClass) # TypeError: reload() argument must be module
reload(myModule) # NameError: name 'myModule' is not defined
reload(myModules.myModule)  # NameError: name 'myModules' is not defined
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: reload component Y imported with 'from X import Y'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739924/python-reload-component-y-imported-with-from-x-import-y)

Comment: Is @TokenMacGuy's answer missing something?  If not, you should accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have a module to reload.  when you use the `from foo import bar`, unless `bar` is a module (it looks like it isn't, in your case) you will have to use another import statement.

```
from myModules.myModule import myClass
# this will cause myModule.py to be evaluated.  only myClass is in scope

from myModules import myModule
# since myModule has already been imported, myModule.py is not evaluated again. 
# but now myModule is in scope.

reload(myModule)
# this will cause myModule.py to be evaluated again.
```

If, for some reason, you don't want two imports, the already imported module can also be found in `sys.modules`

Comment: Is it considered bad style when importing classes as I do? Or does it not matter?

Comment: It's not bad style. It depends what you need from an import. If you only need MyClass, you import only MyClass. If you need everything in MyModule, you import MyModule (and access MyClass with **MyModule.MyClass**)

Comment: I personally prefer to always import modules, but this is not the reason.  Using modules can keep you out of circular import trouble, and also tends to reduce the total number of global names for the reader to keep track of.  If you are concerned about how your imports are interacting with `reload()`, then you probably *are* doing something wrong, it's only reasonable useful when programming interactively, to reload a module's contents that you have changed.