# Eclipse PyDev's Console cannot notice the change of imported file

Tags: python, eclipse, console, pydev

I am new for both PyDev and Python, and Looking for help for following question.
Suppose I have two files test1.py and test2.py, and their contents are as follows:

## test1.py

```
from test2 import a
print a
```

## test2.py

```
a=1
```

When I run the console, and use `%run test1` to run the code test1.py, everything is fine, and I got output `1`. However, if I changed the value of a in the file test2.py (such as from 1 to 2), and then use `%run test1`, I will still get `1`. I tried to use `execfile('test2.py')` to reload test2.py, which however doesn't work.

Every thing will be ok, if I use the terminal to run code, i.e. `python test1.py`, which will notice the change in test2.py whenever I run it. Only the console in eclipse is weird.

Note: The Operating System that I use is Windows 7.

Thanks for any help or attention in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, PyDev has a builtin solution for that too:

Enable `User Module Deleter` at `preferences > pydev > interactive console > user module deleter` and then, instead of execfile or %run, use `runfile('file_to_run.py')` -- note that if you have the editor opened in PyDev, you can use `Ctrl+Alt+Enter` to send that statement to the interactive console for you.

By doing so, `runfile` will remove all the modules previously imported and reimport your new modules...

Another option is really reloading manually through the `reload(module)` function.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to handle this. The key to do this is the command `reload()`. But not with current content, because it is a bad idea to import a variable from a module, i.e. `from test2 import a`.

So the file 'test1.py' should be changed.

## test1.py

```
import test2
print test2.a
```

And after this, whenever I changed 'test2.py', I run the code `reload(test2)`, and then use `%run test1` will give the correct answer of `a`.

Following link is similar question with more detail explanation for this stuff is given below.
[Python: reload component Y imported with 'from X import Y'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739924/python-reload-component-y-imported-with-from-x-import-y)