# Reload component from module in Python3

Tags: python-3.x

This question is similar to [[Python: reload component Y imported with 'from X import Y'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739924/python-reload-component-y-imported-with-from-x-import-y) ]. However, clearly reload doesnt work in python 3.

I initially had

```
from vb2GP import vb_Estep
```

However, due to a bug I modified vb_Estep. When I try to reload using `importlib.reload(vb_Estep)` I get the error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-61-72416bca3a93>", line 1, in <module>
    importlib.reload(vb_Estep)

  File "/Users/sachin/anaconda/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 139, in reload
    raise TypeError("reload() argument must be module")

TypeError: reload() argument must be module
```

I even tried `importlib(vb2GP.vb_Estep)` where I get the error `NameError: name 'vb2GP' is not defined`, which makes sense since I never imported vb2GP to start off with.

So the **question is**, how do you reload compnents in Python3 using `importlib`.

Comment: Did you modify `vb_Estep` in place (if it is mutable) or did you rebind the name to some new object (which would be the only way to "modify" it if it's not mutable)?

Comment: I just rewrote a few lines. I'm pretty new to python so not entirely sure if that answers the question or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `reload` function you're using only works on modules, not directly on objects imported from them. To use it, you'll need to import `vb2GP` first, then call `reload` on the module object, then extract the reloaded `vb_Estep` value from the new version of the module.

```
import importlib

import vb2GP                      # import the old version of the module
vb2GP = importlib.reload(vb2GP)   # reload it
vb_Estep = vb2GP.vb_Estep         # get a reference to the value in the reloaded module
```

But that might not actually be necessary, depending on how exactly you "modified" the current `vb_Estep` value. If you have only rebound the name to a new value, you can just re-import the old one without doing any `reload`ing at all (just use `from vb2GP import vb_Estep` again). It's only if you modified the value in place (e.g. by changing its contents or attributes without rebinding the variable name itself) that the `reload` code above will be needed.