# Running Brightway with project dir on user-defined directory

Tags: brightway

The default directory in which Brightway stores projects and all associated components is determined by `appdirs`. Indeed, in `bw2data.projects`, the project directory is set as:

`data_dir = appdirs.user_data_dir(LABEL, "pylca")`

For example, for my Windows install , this is C:\users\me\AppData\Local\pylca\Brightway3.

I would like for one of my projects to be on an external network-based disk. This is for a used project, not just for cold storage. Is there functionality within Brightway to change the location of a project?

Comment: You can solve your problem by setting the `BRIGHTWAY2_DIR` environment variable. The page in the documentation [Setting BRIGHTWAY2_DIR in a virtual environment](https://docs.brightwaylca.org/faq.html#setting-brightway2-dir-in-a-virtual-environment) explains very well how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative procedure if you want to change BRIGHTWAY2_DIR in Python, this works:

```
import os
os.environ['BRIGHTWAY2_DIR']='path/to/my/other/dir'
from brightway2 import *
```

Despite interesting leads such as [this one on reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739924/python-reload-component-y-imported-with-from-x-import-y/11724154#11724154), I have been unable to make this work if there was a brightway2 import before setting the BRIGHTWAY2_DIR environment variable.