# python function arguments are not identified by the main code in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, function, jupyter-notebook

I have two python files, one is `func.py` where in this file I define the function

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def lineplot(x,y,clip):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(x,y,'k-', linewidth=0.2)
    ax.plot(lo,la,marker='.', color='r')
```

Then, in my second file `main.ipynb`, I call this function

```
import func as f

f.lineplot(x,y,clip)
```

I run `main.ipynb` and it has an error `name lo is not given`.

I find `lo` and `la` in function `lineplot` are not in the argument list. So I change `func.py` as

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def lineplot(x,y,clip,lo,la):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(x,y,'k-', linewidth=0.2)
    ax.plot(lo,la,marker='.', color='r')
```

After that, I revise `main.ipynb`,

```
import func as f

f.lineplot(x,y,clip,lo,la)
```

but this time it gives me an error:
`lineplot() takes 3 positional arguments but 5 were given`

Does anybody know why it happens and how to fix it? I use Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Did you `reload()` the function in `main` after you changed it in `func`?

Comment: Does `import func as f` equivalent to load the revised function to the main environment?

Comment: Not if you haven't closed/restarted the jupyter kernel, if the module exists in the namespace it may not reload when you call import again. See [this question for ideal methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739924/python-reload-component-y-imported-with-from-x-import-y)