# Proper way to reload a python module from the console

Tags: python

I'm debugging from the python console and would like to reload a module every time I make a change so I don't have to exit the console and re-enter it.  I'm doing:

```
>>> from project.model.user import *
>>> reload(user)
```

but I receive:

```
>>>NameError: name 'user' is not defined
```

What is the proper way to reload the entire user class?  Is there a better way to do this, perhaps auto-updating while debugging?

Thanks.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

As asked, the best you can do is

```
>>> from project.models.user import *
>>> import project # get module reference for reload
>>> reload(project.models.user) # reload step 1
>>> from project.models.user import * # reload step 2
```

it would be better and cleaner if you used the user module directly, rather than doing `import *` (which is almost never the right way to do it). Then it would just be

```
>>> from project.models import user
>>> reload(user)
```

This would do what you want. But, it's not very nice. If you really need to reload modules so often, I've got to ask: why?

My suspicion (backed up by previous experience with people asking similar questions) is that you're testing your module. There are lots of ways to test a module out, and doing it by hand in the interactive interpreter is among the worst ways. Save one of your sessions to a file and use [`doctest`](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html), for a quick fix. Alternatively, write it out as a program and use `python -i`. The only really great solution, though, is using the [`unittest`](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html) module.

If that's not it, hopefully it's something better, not worse. There's really no good use of `reload` (in fact, it's removed in 3.x). It doesn't work effectively-- you might reload a module but leave leftovers from previous versions. It doesn't even work on all kinds of modules-- extension modules will not reload properly, or sometimes even break horribly, when reloaded.

The context of using it in the interactive interpreter doesn't leave a lot of choices as to what you are doing, and what the real best solution would be. Outside it, sometimes people used `reload()` to implement plugins etc. This is dangerous at best, and can frequently be done differently using either `exec` (ah the evil territory we find ourselves in), or a segregated process.

Comment: What I'm doing to find this question, is I'm using the console to explore a data structure imported from JSON. I want to use "reload" to keep some functions in my text editor that traverse the structure in different ways, edit them, then rerun them, without having to quit out of the console. Still, if Python can't support that cleanly, for implementation reasons such as this inability to remove "leftovers", I guess I must be wrong to want to do it ;-p +1 for the answer that lets me do it anyway, though.

Comment: +1 for showing me that I should, really really, be writing tests instead of doing things in interpreter by hand, even for fine tuning. This would also be useful for future non-regression testing.

Comment: You'll rarely see me arguing against unit tests but there are definitely scenarios when you're prototyping where this would be valuable. Not disagreeing with the overall sentiment, but 'one of the worst ways' is a pretty severe value judgement.

Comment: Naively with medwards.  I found my way here b/c using reload inside of python debugger.  When debugging an editable package I was hoping to modify and reload a module and call the routine in question, rather than exit python and start from scratch each time.   Why is that not a valid and use of reload()?  Scenario has nothing to do with unit tests.

Comment: 3.x keeps reload. It just moved it out of built-in functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961162/reloading-module-giving-nameerror-name-reload-is-not-defined

Comment: Alright. After grumpily coming back to this reload nonsense, I've decided to go ahead and finally learn how to debug properly. Thanks for the motivation, and for anyone else having the same trouble, I'm using this website as guidelines for now: https://codeburst.io/how-i-use-python-debugger-to-fix-code-279f11f75866

Answer (score 22):

For python3.4+, reload has been moved to the `importlib` module. you can use `importlib.reload()`. You can refer to **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/437591/6521116)**.

```
>>> import importlib
>>> import project # get module reference for reload
>>> importlib.reload(project.models.user) # reload step 1
>>> from project.models.user import * # reload step 2
```

For `python3` versions before `3.4`, the module to import is `imp` (instead of `importlib`)

Comment: The imp module is deprecated in favor of importlib since Python 3.4. Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html

Comment: This should have been an update to the accepted answer. It was clearly copied from it, the comments are still there...

Answer (score 8):

IPython can reload modules before executing every new line:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

Where `%autoreload 2`reloads "all modules (except those excluded by %aimport) every time before executing the Python code typed."

See the docs:

- https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html

Answer (score 6):

You can't use reload() in a effective way.

Python does not provide an effective support for reloading or unloading of previously imported 
modules; module references makes it impractical to reload a module because references could exist in many places of your program.

Python 3 has removed reload() feature entirely.

Comment: It's not module references that do it: reload() actually mutates the module object. It's the references to functions and classes inside the module that break things (in particular, the references generated by from foo import *).

Comment: Yes i agree, and you could have other program modules that has imported the module you want to unload().

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you've got to use:

```
>>> from project.model import user
>>> reload(user)
```

I don't know off the top of my head of something which will automatically reload modules at the interactive prompt… But I don't see any reason one shouldn't exist (in fact, it wouldn't be too hard to implement, either…)

Now, you *could* do something like this:

```
from types import ModuleType
import sys
_reload_builtin = reload
def reload(thing):
    if isinstance(thing, ModuleType):
        _reload_builtin(thing)
    elif hasattr(thing, '__module__') and thing.__module__:
        module = sys.modules[thing.__module__]
        _reload_builtin(module)
    else:
        raise TypeError, "reload() argument must be a module or have an __module__"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [`twisted.python.rebuild.rebuild`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.0.0/api/twisted.python.rebuild.html).

Answer (score 0):

```py
    from test_reload import add_test
```

where `test_reload` is a module, and `add_test` is a function
if you changed the function `add_test`, of course you need to reload this function.
then you can do this:

```py
    import imp
    imp.reload(test_reload)
    from test_reload import add_test
```

this will refresh the function `add_test`.

so you need to add

```
imp.reload(test_reload)
from test_reload import add_test  --add this line in your code
```

Comment: It would be better if you add some information to explain your answer/code.

Answer (score 0):

As of Python 3.4 you can use [importlib.reload(module)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload)

```py
>>> from importlib import reload
>>> from project.model import user
>>> reload(user)
```