# Reload multiple different python files in Blender

Tags: python, import, blender

I am just starting with Blender and need some guidance. Sorry if this is basic, i tried googling but unfortunately couldn't find anything useful.

I need to import multiple python files into one in Blender.

Currently I am doing:

```
dir = os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath)
if not dir in sys.path:
sys.path.append(dir )
import ladder
import table

# this next part forces a reload in case you edit the source after you first start the blender session

import importlib

importlib.reload(ladder)
from ladder import *
importlib.reload(table)
from table import *
```

I tried solutions in this post as well but didn't help:

[How to reload all imported modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405600/how-to-reload-all-imported-modules)

Will really appreciate any help possible.