# Reloading a Python extension module from IPython

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, cython

Using Cython, I am developing an extension module which gets build as an .so file. I then test it using IPython. During development, I frequently need to make changes and rebuild. I also need to exit the IPython shell and reenter all commands. Reimporting the module with

```
import imp
imp.reload(Extension)
```

does not work, the code is not updated. Is there a way for me to avoid restarting the IPython shell after I rebuild the module?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

C extensions cannot be reloaded without restarting the process (see [this official Python bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue1144263) for more info).

Since you are already using IPython, I might recommend using one of the two-process interfaces such as the Notebook or QtConsole, if it's acceptable to you.  These allow you to easily *restart* the kernel process, which allows to you load the module anew.  Obviously, this isn't as convenient as reload for a Python module because you have to re-execute to get back to the same state.  But that is not avoidable, so the point is to mitigate the inconvenience.

I find the notebook interface the most convenient for developing extensions, because it provides the easiest way to get back to the same state:

1. rebuild the extension
2. restart kernel
3. Run All to re-execute the notebook

and you are back to the same state with the new version of the extension. Mileage may vary, depending on how costly your interactive work is to re-run, but it has served me well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting an `autoreload` in the `ipython shell`, [documentation here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/extensions/autoreload.html).

Set `autoreload`

```
In [1]: %load_ext autoreload

In [2]: %autoreload 2
```

Set `autoreload` on specific module

```
%aimport foo
```

Also, take a look at [`dreload`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.10.1/html/interactive/reference.html#dreload) (more on `dreload` [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html)) and the [run-magic](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.10.1/html/interactive/tutorial.html#the-run-magic-command)

Comment: It does not work for my case, the autoreload documentation states that: "C extension modules cannot be reloaded, and so cannot be autoreloaded."

Answer (score -2):

IPython provides a way to [automatically reload modules](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/extensions/autoreload.html):

```
In [1]: %load_ext autoreload
In [2]: %autoreload 2
```

else you can use (edited: python 2 only)

```
reload(module)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/961219/843194) for python3 reload.

Comment: Humorous, you answered 5 seconds after me. Very cool when it happens.

Comment: `reload` is not a built-in in Python 3 I believe.

Comment: :x I would have redirected to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364050/reloading-submodules-in-ipython) but I'm not familiar enough with the system @cls: oups, my bad