# How to automatically reload modules in IPython?

Tags: module, ipython

Before I begin, I want to say that I am not a programmer; I am a geek and an engineer. Thus, I love coding and use it academically. Stackoverflow taught me more than 80% of what I know about python.

My problem is I need to manually reload the modules in my scripts by first importing importlib into my terminal and than using `importlib.reload(*modulename*)` to reload them. I want my IPython terminal to automatically reload the modules in my python scripts when I run them through my IPython terminal. This functionally was provided in previous version using the magic command `%autoreload`, which does not seem to work for me.

I have looked @ the IPython documentation (link 1), tried using the `%load_ext autoreload` command (link 2) and the `import ipy_autoreload` followed by `%autoreload 2` command (link 3). I found more than 4 other answers in stackoverflow telling me to do the things in either link 2 or 3; it didn't work for me. If anyone knows how to bring back autoreloading, it would make my fingers a bit happier.

Link 1: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html

Link 2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18216967/5762140

Link 3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4765191/5762140

I am using a 64 bit installation of Windows 7. I have IPython 4.0.1 which came with my installation of Anaconda3 (3.18.9 64bit). Screenies about my error traceback from the IPython terminal when i try to use `%load_ext autoreload` can be provided on request.

Answer (score 77):

All the links you have above use commands within ipython. You should try editing your config file. Open up your terminal and complete the following steps.

Step 1: Make sure you have the latest ipython version installed

```
$ ipython --version
```

Step 2: find out where your config file is

```
$ ipython profile create
```

Step 3: Open the config file with an editor based on the location of your config file. I use atom. For example:

```
$ atom ~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
```

Step 4: Look for the following lines in the config file:

```py
c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = []
```

change it to:

```py
c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = ['autoreload']
```

and then uncomment that line

find:

```py
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = []
```

change it to:

```py
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%autoreload 2']
```

and then uncomment that line

Done.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine for me  :). do you know how to set default starting directory for ipython ? I tried with c.InteractiveShell.ipython_dir but it doesn't seem to be the relevant option ...

Comment: @A.Joly I would be happy to try and answer your question, but as a best practice for StackOverflow, as your question pertains to a different topic, please first search for an answer already given to your question, and then if you can't find one, post a new question.

Comment: That's what I've done  ;) I found the answer, if anyone interested, here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45939209/how-to-set-default-path-automatically-in-ipython

Comment: @A.Joly Outstanding. Thx!

Comment: It should be `c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%autoreload 2']`, because you already load the extension by adding it to `c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions`