# How to set default path automatically in IPython

Tags: python, ipython

I'm using WingIDE for development and Ipython for running my scripts. I'm facing some inconvenience on several points:

- Whenever I update my code, I have to reload my module in order to update it in IPython. To solve that I followed [Jomonsugi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6706416/jomonsugi)'s answer in the following link: [How to automatically reload modules in IPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037815/how-to-automatically-reload-modules-in-ipython)
  and it works.
- Each time I launch IPython, my path is set to my exe's location and I have to cd to my script's directory. 
  I tried to change directory automatically when launching IPython by setting the parameter `c.InteractiveShell.ipython_dir = <mypath>` in `ipython_config.py` but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to set the default path? Is there a particular parameter to set in ipython_config.py?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use your `startup.py` file.  It should be located somewhere like:

```
C:/Users/yourname/.ipython/profile_default
```

If it's not there already, create it.  Then use

```
import os
os.chdir('C:/Users/mypath')
```

Those two lines will then be run at IPython startup.

Source: IPython.org > [Startup Files](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/config/overview.html#startup-files)

Answer (score 3):

I’m sure Brad Solomon’s answer is right for his version of IPython, but I’ve just downloaded IPython with `pip install ipython` and my startup files are in a directory nested one deeper than his. My IPython version is 7.18.1, and the start-up files are located in `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/`.  There is a `README` there which states

```
This is the IPython startup directory

.py and .ipy files in this directory will be run *prior* to any code
or files specified via the exec_lines or exec_files configurables
whenever you load this profile.

Files will be run in lexicographical order, so you can control the
execution order of files with a prefix, e.g.::

        00-first.py
        50-middle.py
        99-last.ipy
```

That’s pretty self-descriptive, but I would add to this (for anyone coming here from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037815/how-to-automatically-reload-modules-in-ipython)) that `%load_ext autoreload` is an IPython command, so you might want to create a file `startup.ipy` with contents something like this:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
print('IPython startup file - created 2020/9/28')
```