# Python3 - reload() can not be called on __import__ object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, reload, python-3.3

Ok so for a number of reasons, I've been using `s = __import__('parse')` for the longest time in Python2, now I sorta need to being my transitions to Python3 for certain projects (mainly due to SSL).

But there's no `reload()` equivilant in Python3 as far as i've spotted.
There's only one option:

```
import parse
parse.reload() #works
```

But I really, really need this to work:

```
parse = __import__('parse')
parse.reload()
```

or

```
reload(parse)
```

Any ideas on how to get it working in Python3?

Comment: Think i found it -.-  `import imp` && `imp.reload(parse)`?

Comment: `from imp import reload`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reloading module giving NameError: name 'reload' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961162/reloading-module-giving-nameerror-name-reload-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The `reload` built-in function has been moved to `importlib` module in Python 3.4:

```
In [18]: from importlib import reload

In [19]: reload?
Reload the module and return it.

The module must have been successfully imported before.
```

As pointed out by @JPaget in comments [`reload()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) function has been moved from [`imp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html#module-imp) to [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib) module in **Python 3.4+**. From [what's new in Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#importlib):

> The `reload()` function has been moved from `imp` to `importlib` as part of
>   the `imp` module deprecation

Comment: As of Python 3.4, imp is deprecated.  Use importlib instead:
    `from importlib import reload`