# Reload a Module in Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, python-module

I know this might sound like a really stupid question but whatever. I've made a small script in Python and I've made some changes while in a shell. Normally, on an OS X computer (It's running Python 2.7), I would simply type in `reload(the_module)` and it would reload my module that includes the changes that I have made. However, when I am reloading the module here (on windows python v. 3.4), it simply gives me this:

```
>>> reload(instfile)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    reload(instfile)
NameError: name 'reload' is not defined
```

And then when I type in `imp.reload(my_module)`, it simply says that the function is deprecated. I can't seem to find what the new function (or it's equivalent) would be anywhere so if someone can help me that would be great! :)

Comment: Better target for dupe is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961162/reloading-module-giving-nameerror-name-reload-is-not-defined).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The `imp` module was deprecated in Python 3.4 in favor of the [`importlib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib).  From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html) for the `imp` module:

> Deprecated since version 3.4: The `imp` package is pending deprecation
>   in favor of `importlib`.

So, you should be using the `reload` function from there:

```
>>> import importlib
>>> importlib.reload
<function reload at 0x01BA4030>
>>> importlib.reload(the_module)
```

Comment: I'm missing a step or what? Still there seems no way to reload a module but to close and reopen the command shell, 80s style.

Comment: @user3285866 Run the actual function `importlib.reload(MODULE)`

Comment: This method might not override other modules' references to the reloaded module. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61617169/2642356 for a solution to that.