# Disable caching of importing modules in ipython-notebook

Tags: python, python-import

I'm importing a module in ipython-notebook. It's taking 10 seconds. If in the same session, I'm importing that same module again it's taking 0.000004 secs. How to disable this inbuild caching of importing of modules ?

Comment: Instead of disabling the cache, how about using [reload](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) or in Python3, [importlib.reload](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27387786/190597)?

Comment: No, that's exactly what I don't want.
Example :-
from a import b 
(takes 10 seconds)
reload(b)
(takes just 0.00004 seconds)
I want the reloading to take the same time as before.

Comment: It's probably nothing to do with IPython. The first time you import a module, Python executes it and stores a module object. Every time after that, you just get a reference to the module object. This is how Python imports work, and if you do find a way to change it, you'll probably break all kinds of things. What are you trying to do with it?