# Python - Changes to imported file do not take effect

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, enthought

I have a file called `test_file`, which is designed to test another file, called `file`. 'test_file' also contains a `.txt` file in the same directory.  When I update `file`, save, select 'Change to Editor Directory...', then run `test_file`, Enthought does not seem to recognize that `file` was updated. Initially I thought I had to select the 'Change to Editor Directory' option every time I updated `file`, and so I did, but `test_file` was still printing 'success', even after I deliberately edited `file` so that `test_file` should print false. (Yes, I'm sure that it should have printed false as I added a bunch of gibberish code into `file`, and even code that shouldn't run, such as throwing in `return` statements with blatantly incorrect indentation). So, essentially, Enthought Canopy isn't realizing that I've updated `file`.

However, if I save and quit everything, *reopen* Enthought, select 'Change to Editor Directory', then run `test_file`, it prints the correct outcome.

This is very frustrating, because I spent days debugging *correct* code before I realized this. It has me *very* concerned because I don't know if what I tested in the past is actually correct, and I don't want this to happen in the future.

What is the possible cause of this? (Note: I don't know if this is an Enthought issue or a Python issue)

Answer (score 9):

It's hard to say without seeing the code, but I suspect that `file` is being imported with a command equivalent to `import file`. Python caches imported modules, and so it would not pick up the changes in `file`. This is a Python feature, and is independent of Enthought Canopy.

If that's the case, you can solve the problem by adding a call to `reload` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) after the import in `test_file`, to explicitly force a reload of the module:

```
  import file
  reload(file)
```

Comment: Agreed. For details, see [this knowledge base article](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469240-IPython-After-editing-a-module-changes-are-not-effective-without-kernel-restart)

Answer (score 4):

With Python **2.x**, *@pberkes*' answer works. For Python 3, you can proceed as follows:

***For Python versions >= 3.4:***

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(module)
```

***For Python versions 3.0–3.3:***

```
import imp
imp.reload(module)
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33409066/2851999)