# Why was reload removed from python builtins in the switch to python3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, reload, built-in

I recently made the switch from python 2 to python 3. [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html) reads: "**Removed reload(). Use imp.reload()**" It doesn't really say why though.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961162/reloading-module-giving-error-reload-is-not-defined) question describes how it's done now in python 3. Does anyone have any idea why it's been removed from the built-ins and now requires **imp** or **importlib** to reload? When testing a program as you build it using the interactive prompt, having reload right there by default is super convenient. Obviously I can get that back by doing something like

```
from imp import reload
```

It's just another line of code every time I open an interactive prompt to test code. What's the reasoning behind this change?

Comment: It is must less universal or important the remaining built-ins. Being handy in one specific context of execution does not change this.

Comment: I think it was because too many people saw it sitting there in builtins and used it without understanding its limitations.  Putting it in a module made it less likely that people would use it without knowing what they were doing.  I can't find a reliable source for this info though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`reload()` was removed from the built-ins as one of the *Python Regrets* Guido expressed in a [Keynote address at OSCON 2002](http://www.authorstream.com/Presentation/TechGuy-1495-paython-regrets-language-c-plus-programming-pythonregrets-education-ppt-powerpoint/) (slide 6). See [PEP 3100 - *Miscellaneous Python 3.0 Plans*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3100/) which names several changes that trace their origin to that talk.

From the slide I'd say he expected `exec()` to be used; that'd certainly cover the most common usecase of iteratively developing some code in an editor and re-testing it in an interactive interpreter.

However, when discussing [PEP 3121 - *Extension Module Initialization and Finalization*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3121/) Guido quickly found out that he missed the function:

> > Yes; I'm not certain whether module reloading continues to be supported
> >     in Py3k or not. If not, it should be removed from the PEP, if yes, it
> >     should be specified.
>
> I'm already missing the reload() builtin, so I think it should be kept
>   around in some form. I expect some form of reload functionality will
>   remain available, perhaps somewhere in the imp module.

So, in short, `reload()` was removed first, then when it was missed, `imp.reload()` was added. It didn't really need to be a built-in anyway, I certainly use it only rarely.

In Python 3.4 [the function was moved](http://bugs.python.org/issue18193) to [`importlib.reload()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload).

Comment: Note that `reload` was [recently moved](http://bugs.python.org/issue18193) to `importlib`, so if you are writing new code targetting current versions, you should use `importlib.reload` directly to avoid later problems when the function eventually becomes officially deprecated and later removed.