# How to switch Backend with Keras (from TensorFlow to Theano)

Tags: backend, theano, keras

I tried to switch Backend with Keras (from TensorFlow to Theano) but did not manage.
I followed the temps described [here](https://keras.io/backend/) but it doesn't work. I created a keras.json in the keras' directory (as it did not exist) but it doesn't change anything when I import it from Python.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Create a `.keras` (note the `.` in front) folder in you home directory and put the `keras.json` file there.

For example, `/home/DaniPaniz/.keras/keras.json` (or `~/.keras/keras.json` in short) if you are on a UNIX like system (MacOS X, Linux, *BSD). On Windows you want to create the folder `%USERPROFILE%/.keras` and put the JSON file there.

Alternatively, you can also set the environment variable `KERAS_BACKEND`:

```
KERAS_BACKEND=theano python mymodel.py
```

Comment: You can also put `import os; os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = 'theano'` before importing `keras`

Answer (score 34):

In case you want to change the config permanently, the json is available here: `~/.keras/keras.json` and you can change the backend.

To do this dynamically in python 2.7 you can run:

```py
from keras import backend as K
import os

def set_keras_backend(backend):

    if K.backend() != backend:
        os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = backend
        reload(K)
        assert K.backend() == backend

set_keras_backend("theano")
```

Comment: the function reload isn't known on my machine

Comment: If you're using python 3, reload is not built-in. To use reload in python 3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/961219

Comment: Python >= 3.4: `import importlib; importlib.reload(K)`

Comment: Still (using the `reload` function of the `importlib` library) the backend is not being dynamically changed for me. Any ideas on how to overcome this issue is really appreciated. @Wmol @Demitri

Answer (score 19):

I had an issue where I could not `from keras import backend` at all until I set the backend to theano. The provided answers should work if you can import backend, but if not, just use:

```py
import os
os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = 'theano'
import keras as ks
# Using Theano backend.
```

Answer (score 14):

In windows, you need to find .keras folder in your C drive. Most probably, it will be somewhere in **C:/users/username/**. There you will find .keras folder, it contains a json file, **keras.json**, open it.
You will see:

```
{
“backend”: “tensorflow”,
“floatx”: “float32”,
“epsilon”: 1e-07
}
```

more or less.
**replace 'tensorflow' with 'theano'.** and save the file.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using windows you can run from command line:

`set "KERAS_BACKEND=theano"`

Answer (score 5):

```py
from keras import backend as K
from os import environ

# user defined function to change keras backend
def set_keras_backend(backend):
    if K.backend() != backend:
       environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = backend
       reload(K)
       assert K.backend() == backend

# call the function with "theano"
set_keras_backend("theano")
```

Comment: Could you please explain how this solves the problem?

Comment: @StephenRauch When you import keras, it picks up "tensorflow" as a default backend. If you need to switch to "theano", the above lines will do that job.

Comment: name 'reload' is not defined?

Comment: Did not work for me as I've created my own question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62735466/how-can-i-change-the-backend-of-keras-dynamically

Comment: @talha06
which system are you using - Windows, Mac or Linux?
I'd recommend editing your `keras.json` file. So locate the file and change it accordingly.

Comment: @HafizurRahman Yes, I'm aware of that - but I need to change the backend dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Type following on command prompt and press enter:

```
%USERPROFILE%/.keras/keras.json
```

Change backend in the opened text file and save it. You are done.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux systems, the hidden .keras directory will be created in the user’s home directory. To observe whether or not it has been created, run the following command from your home directory (the -a allows you to see hidden files and directories).

```
ls –a
```

If the directory is there, then cd into it and modify the keras.json file. If it’s not there, then create the directory with

```
mkdir .keras
```

Then create the file with

```
touch keras.json
```

Then edit the file to make the config changes you referenced to change the backend engine to Theano.

This process is covered fully in [this video](https://youtu.be/sRF_-bwxru4).

Answer (score 0):

Termux - Android 11 -
Finally working with
H5py  3.4.0
Keras 2.2.0
Theano 1.0.5
Numpy 1.17.5

I find that packages sometimes do not install when built and --update.   *****
You need to manually uninstall / install.  .. I fond

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this possible anymore.

After some searching I came across this keras 2.4.0 release note, where they state that they discountinued multi-backend Keras.

Am not exactly an expert so I can't tell if this is possible anymore. You might try using an older keras version.

The release Note page: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.4.0