# changing keras backend to Theano in Ipython Notebook

Tags: python, deep-learning, theano, jupyter-notebook, keras

I did change the `keras.json` file as instructed on the [Keras documentation page](https://keras.io/backend/). But in my Ipython notebook, it still says I am using Tensorflow as backend.

[image]

Maybe it is related to the Jupyter settings somehow? Please kindly help. I don't even know how to figure out where the problem came from. Thanks!

Comment: See [this](http://www.nodalpoint.com/switch-keras-backend/).

Comment: Thanks @ParagS.Chandakkar. However it does not work for me. When I do `keras.backend.backend()`, it still says `tensorflow`. Maybe I could solve thsis issue by uninstalling tensorflow?

Comment: have you tried KERAS_BACKEND=theano jupyter notebook --no-browser --ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx?  and then keras.backend.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')

Comment: DId you try turning it off and on again?

Comment: @maz no I havn't. What ip address should i use to replace the xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx as you suggested?

Comment: @ThomasPinetz No I don't think I did that - don't even know how to ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the following at the start of the notebook:

```
import os
os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "theano"
import keras; import keras.backend
if keras.backend.backend() != 'theano':
    raise BaseException("This script uses other backend")
else:
    keras.backend.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
    print("Backend ok")
```

Basically environment KERAS_BACKEND can be overwriten at some point by Jupyter so this is one way to force it to be something before you import keras.backend.

Comment: I am receiving........BaseException: This script uses other backend  ...

Answer (score 1):

## What works in python 2.7 - dynamically changing Keras backend

```
# When I executed the suggestion -- the output I got..
BaseExceptionTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-c4352a2d60e6> in <module>()
      3 import keras; import keras.backend
      4 if keras.backend.backend() != 'theano':
----> 5     raise BaseException("This script uses other backend")
      6 else:
      7     keras.backend.set_image_dim_ordering('th')

BaseException: This script uses other backend
```

-- Not sure, how this would help if we are not able to dynamically change the backend.

-- Instead what helped me was the following:
[How to switch Backend with Keras (from TensionFlow to Theano)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177658/how-to-switch-backend-with-keras-from-tensionflow-to-theano)

**Code in iPython**

```
from keras import backend; print(backend._BACKEND)
from keras import backend as K
import os
def set_keras_backend(backend):
    if K.backend() != backend:
        os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = backend
        reload(K)
        assert K.backend() == backend
print ("Change Keras Backend to Theano")        
set_keras_backend("theano")  
from keras import backend; print(backend._BACKEND)
```

**Output in iPython**

```
tensorflow
Change Keras Backend to Theano
theano
```

Comment: for python 3.4 and above, use `import importlib; importlib.reload` instead of `reload`.