# How to fix import keras error with python console

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I import keras with tensorflow backend, but this error is occured.
I install tensoflow, is worked before. but some error message occured, it doesn't work.

```
>>>import keras <-- command
Using TensorFlow backend.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\bak40\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\bak40\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "C:\Users\bak40\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "C:\Users\bak40\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "C:\Users\bak40\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\bak40\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\bak40\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Users\bak40\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 7, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\Users\bak40\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: 지정된 프로시저를 찾을 수 없습니다.
```

thank you.

Comment: Hope this works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177658/how-to-switch-backend-with-keras-from-tensorflow-to-theano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to import with `tensorflow.keras` or `import keras`

Keras switched to tensorflow.keras, which is a part of tensorflow >= 1.10.0.