# how to fix "import keras not working" error

Tags: python, keras

I have used Keras remotely, such as on Colab and AWS. Today, I tried to install Keras on my laptop using pip3 install keras, and the message was that keras was already installed on the computer (I must have installed it before):

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Requirement already satisfied: keras in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Keras-2.4.3-py3.7.egg (2.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h5py-2.10.0-py3.7-macosx-10.15-x86_64.egg (from keras) (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from keras) (1.16.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyYAML-5.3.1-py3.7-macosx-10.15-x86_64.egg (from keras) (5.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.14 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from keras) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from h5py->keras) (1.12.0)
```

However, when I tried to `import keras`, I received this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-21-88d96843a926>", line 1, in <module>
    import keras
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2018, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'ModuleNotFoundError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 1095, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 313, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 347, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 1502, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 1460, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v1 import app
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/_api/v1/app/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform.app import run
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/platform/app.py", line 23, in <module>
    from absl.app import run as _run
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'absl'
```

I Googled to find similar problems and I found some suggestions to try `sudo pip3 install keras`. Keras was downloaded again. However, when I typed `import keras`, it still produced errors.

Also, I read this Stack Overflow question: [How to fix import keras error with python console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57156410/how-to-fix-import-keras-error-with-python-console), but the solution does not work for me as I am calling a library which calls `import keras`, so I need the `import keras` command to work (I can't make it call `import tensorflow.keras`).

Why is this error happening?

Note: I am using Python 3.7.5. I checked the version of pip through `pip --version`, getting this message:

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Also, I am running this code in Jupyter Notebook. I have checked that Python 3.7 is being run by Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Can you add your python as well pip version?

Comment: I added it to the question! My python version is 3.7.5 and pip version is 20.0.2.

Comment: Try `pip install absl`

Answer (score 1):

Try installing tensorflow first:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Then access keras via tensorflow

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
import tensorflow as tf
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're running your script with `python3`. Macs and some other computers come with Python 2.7 installed as the default for `python`, which will bamboozle you daily.

If that doesn't work, set up a virtual environment: [Using Python 3 in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842713/using-python-3-in-virtualenv)

Comment: Hi Alex! I am using Python 3.7.5 (I double checked when launching Jupyter Notebook (it says in the heading of the window), and by printing Python's version in code.