# Downloading Python 3 manager module - reload is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting this error while downloading manager module:

[image: error screenshot]

I am using:

```
sudo pip3 install manager
```

and I get the error:

```
NameError: name 'reload' is not defined
```

Comment: Please post your error and the related code *as text*!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961162/reloading-module-giving-nameerror-name-reload-is-not-defined

Comment: did you install the dependency of PyQt ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly according to the [Github Page of Manager](https://github.com/KelSolaar/Manager) it only runs of either  2.6.7 or Python 2.7.3 while you tried to install it with a `pip3` command implying a Python3+ version.

Additionally you also need PyQt as a dependency.