# when I `pip install mmseg`, I got the error 'NameError: name 'reload' is not defined'

Tags: python, installation, pip, pytorch

However, I got the same problem, when I `pip install mmseg`. So, what should I do?

The log is like that:

```
(Monocular3D) root@gpu9:~/MonoRUn$ pip3 install mmseg -i http://pypi.douban.com/simple/  --trusted-host pypi.douban.com
Looking in indexes: http://pypi.douban.com/simple/
Collecting mmseg
  Downloading http://pypi.doubanio.com/packages/f8/31/3bc9205f39cc8ab37193a6fbb24693993b2f305aba9f35b09fad882107ee/mmseg-1.3.0.tar.gz (817 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 817 kB 4.4 MB/s
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/root/miniconda3/envs/Monocular3D/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-sz89ieuw/mmseg_86227a7da2734023a199ab7a10d06662/setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-sz89ieuw/mmseg_86227a7da2734023a199ab7a10d06662/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-20_hddgd
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-sz89ieuw/mmseg_86227a7da2734023a199ab7a10d06662/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-sz89ieuw/mmseg_86227a7da2734023a199ab7a10d06662/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        reload(sys)
    NameError: name 'reload' is not defined
----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding http://pypi.doubanio.com/packages/c9/3a/a38acf3f3ae401082d74cd283d29a873dd3d1b77dc0c7fb28b80f0348073/mmseg-1.2.4.tar.gz#sha256=e7ba753b7bbefe54b4a7c2e27ed6714d1349e30ad6db9d7f67ce67b80b818f4c (from http://pypi.doubanio.com/simple/mmseg/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mmseg
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mmseg
```

Comment: [smells like a Python 2 - Python 3 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961162/reloading-module-giving-nameerror-name-reload-is-not-defined) What Python are you installing to?

Comment: Actually yes, could you go for `pip3 install mmseg`?

Comment: @Koti It doesn't work, get the same error.

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: `mmseq` was last released in 2012. It very likely does not support Python 3 at all. To use it you *could* install Python 2 alongside Python 3. But I can't recommend that route. As a beginner you should not be investing time in learning Python 2. Those of us who still work in it do so purely because we are supporting or migrating legacy code.

Comment: @Koti OP is obviously using Python 3. `reload` is a built-in in Python 2 but moved to `importlib` in Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me:

```
pip install openmim
mim install mmsegmentation
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to install the latest package version manually. Something like:

`pip install mmseg==1.3.0`

Comment: The log contains the origin information: `NameError: name 'reload' is not defined`. And get the error: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mmseg==1.3.0 ERROR: No matching distribution found for mmseg==1.3.0`

Comment: try `pip install mmsegmentation` instead of  `mmseg`